Store bash glob pattern in a variable
I can use syntax as below to list 6 files named a1b.md, a2b.md, a3b.md, x1y.md, x2y.md, x3y.md in a directory:
ls a{1,2,3}b.md x{1,2,3}y.md

I'd like to use something like this in a bash script; with the braced part stored in a variable, and used in a few places. I've tried a few variations on the code below with no luck. Usually it ends with the message ls: cannot access 'a{1,2,3}b.md': No such file or directory ls: cannot access 'x{1,2,3}y.md': No such file or directory. Can anyone suggest how to do this?
versions="{1,2,3}"
ls a${versions}b.md ls x${versions}y.md


Brace expansions are not part of glob expansions, they're a separate thing and happen before variable expansion, so putting brace expressions in a variable doesn't work. You could use eval, but that has a tendency to parse what you wanted it to... and also a bunch of things you didn't want or expect, and that don't show up in testing but only at the worst possible time later. You should avoid eval if at all possible. Is the version list just single characters? If so, use a square-bracket expression like versions=[123]; ls a${versions}]b.md. If not, an array might be best.

Just use a simple for loop if it's in a script and not directly in shell

@GordonDavisson Thanks. That seems to work.

@GordonDavisson Your comment answers the question, so I think you should post your comment as an independent answer so that other users find it.
